# How to take the value of the struct variable through postman when its type is time.Weekday?

Tags: go

Here I have a struct in golang codegiven below:-

```
type Schedule struct{
 Id           int                 `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
 Day          time.Weekday        `form:"day" json:"day" bson:"day"`
 StartDate    int64               `form:"start_date" json:"start_date" bson:"start_date"`
 EndDate      int64               `form:"end_date" json:"end_date" bson:"end_date"`
 StartTime    int64               `form:"start_time" json:"start_time" bson:"start_time"`
 EndTime      int64               `form:"end_time" json:"end_time" bson:"end_time"`
 AddedOn      int64                `form:"added_on" json:"added_on" bson:"added_on"`
 Occurence    string               `form:"occurence" json:"occurence" bson:"occurence"`
 UpdatedOn    int64                `form:"updated_on" json:"updated_on" bson:"updated_on"`
}
```

Here is the route when I hit the route then it will call a function given below:-

```
 Route{"SaveData", "POST", "/schedule", controller.SaveData},
```

SaveData function:-

```
func SaveData(c *gin.Context) {
    schedule.Day = c.PostForm("day")
    fmt.Println(schedule.Day)
}
```

> #Error is :- cannot use c.PostForm("day") (type string) as type time.Weekday in assignment

Type of Weekdays I want to save :-

```
 type Weekday int

 const (
   Sunday Weekday = iota
   Monday
   Tuesday
   Wednesday
   Thursday
   Friday
   Saturday
 )
```

How will I save the weekday in the database using postman. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go once more. Such basic type manipulations are explained very well there.

Comment: @volker can you give me the link then I will read from there for this

Comment: Done `time.Unix(start_date,0).Weekday().String()` i Will change the time.Weekday value into string

Comment: Show an example of the form value.  More specifically, is it a decimal number ("1", "2", ...) or is it the name of the day ("Sunday", "Monday", ...)?

Comment: @ThunderCat this comes while i run command `go build`

Comment: tour.golang.org. Rule of thumb: Always start with information provided on golang.org.